# android alternative to right caret

Tags: android, user-interface, caret, drilldown

The android design guidelines specifically call out the "right caret" `>` as not being part of the UI. It shouldn't be used to prompt users to drill down into more information.

Unfortunately it doesn't give an alternative, only suggesting that "everything is clickable" and that android users should be used to exploring. This has diverged from reality and I need an alternative indicator for the right caret.

Has something else been standardized or developed? I ask this with the idea that there is an actual answer or burgeoning best practice, otherwise I will implement a right caret

The utility I need is to drill down to more information from a list item. Android doesn't slide menus or views from the left and right, by default, instead it pops up new activity and dialogs, so > may not make that much sense, I just need an equivalent indicator.

thanks for any insight

Comment: There is simply no indicator, list items are basically always clickable as a whole and the transitioning animation does not make it look as if the information is to the right so that indicator does not match the observation. I don't see what that has diverged from reality. Look at e.g. the GMail app, there is no indicator as well.

Comment: Agree with zapl. Also, you probably consider asking at http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To add to what zapl said. When you touch an element on the screen, it will highlight indicating it will do something. You can touch off to cause the event, or move to cancel it. Another point is Android screens don't go left and right but they go up and down, so left and right carets are inappropriate.

Comment: @zapl okay on a related note, lets say I have clickable items, and some of those items are categories of more items, how would I differentiate them?